# Rails 4 How to model a form with a collection of checkboxes with other text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, database-design, models

let me first start by saying this could also be a modeling problem and I am open to model suggestions.

Use Case:
I have a form and I need to allow a user to select a checkbox on the category of their post.  If there is no category that fits their post checking the other category will show a text field for the user to add a custom category. This should would for creating and updating nested modules

DB Modeling

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up {
        Category.create(name: 'Hats')
        Category.create(name: 'Shirts')
        Category.create(name: 'Pants')
        Category.create(name: 'Shoes')
        Category.create(name: 'Other')
      }
    end

    create_table :categorizations, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :post, index: true, null: false
      t.belongs_to :category, index: true, null: false
      t.string :value
    end
  end
end
```

App Models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Controller:

```
  def update

    if @post.update(post_params)
      flash.now[:success] = 'success'
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = @post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end

    render :edit
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    (Category.all - @post.categories).each do |category|
      @post.categorizations.build(category: category)
    end
    @post.categorizations.to_a.sort_by! {|x| x.category.id }
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description,
                                categorizations_attributes: [ :category_id, :value, :_destroy],
                                )
  end
```

View:

```
= f.fields_for :categorizations do |ff|
    = ff.check_box :_destroy, { checked: ff.object.persisted? }, '0', '1'
    = ff.label :_destroy, ff.object.category.name
    = ff.hidden_field :category_id
    = ff.text_field :value if ff.object.category.other?
```

However with the above solution i continue to run in to duplicate record errors when saving.  Not sure why this is happening? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer something like this:

**Models**

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
end
```

**Controller**

```
...
def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
    flash.now[:success] = 'success'
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = @post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  end
  render :edit
end

private

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description, category_ids: [])
end
...
```

**Views**
I always preferer plain `.erb` so,
with help of [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :content -%>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :categories, as: :check_boxes -%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can have checked/unchecked states and destroy easily and cleanly by this way.
In addition, you can add

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :category do |category_fields| %>
  <%= category_fields.input :name -%>
<% end %>
```

to get nested fields for associations, but don't forget to add related params to `strong_params` when you do this.

```
...
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description, category_attributes: [:name])
end
....
```

Comment: What about the form field for the categorization?  So when you select the other category a form field should appear for you to type in other category.

Comment: In my example, you don't need to specify `categorization` manually. By using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Post` and rendering each `category` as a check box, selected categories will be serialized as `category_ids`, which will be called on `Post#category_ids=` method, so `categories` association will be overriden with this last state,  `categorizations` association will be handled automagically, in this scenerio. Was this your question? Or you want to edit `categorization` directly?

Comment: The "Other" category is special in that there is an optional text field that allows the user to add details to the "Other" category.  So that information is stored in the categorization. So a post has a categorization which is associated to category with name other therefor categorization also hold the value other details.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the other in your model, nor it's name! If you're using `form_for` for your `posts`, simply add an unrelated field.

ex: `f.text_field :other_name` to `text_field_tag :other_name`

Manually add your `Other` option to the dropdown collection.

You can add JS to hide and display a hidden text field if other is selected.

In your posts_controller do:

```
def create
  ...
  if params[:other_name]
    post.categories.create(name: param[:other_name])
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the user select the "Other" Category and then storing the text field somewhere else, you should create a new Category instance instead.  You are on the right track with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

The next step would be:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.build_category
end

private
  # don't forget strong parameters!
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(
      ...
      category_attributes: [:name]
      ...
    )
  end
```

Views (using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gems)

```
# app/views/new.html.haml
= f.simple_nested_form_for @job do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :category do |g|
    = g.input :name
```

You can also do it cleaner using Form Objects instead.

**Edit:**
If you need to separate concerns of the Other categories from the Original categories, you can use OO inheritance to do so.  The Rails Way of doing this is [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/models/other_category.rb
class OtherCategory < Category
end

# app/models/original_category.rb
class OriginalCategory < Category
end
```

Comment: With this solution I would have to keep track of the type of category in the model, correct?  It would also insert a lot of categories that I would never display.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by having to keep track of the type of category.  If you're want each of the "Other" categories to be treated differently than the "original" categories, you can subclass them (single table inheritance).

But yes, it would create a lot of categories that you wouldn't display.  Not sure if this is a real issue though.